# Android studio and eclipse + ADT

Tags: android-studio, eclipse-adt

I'am looking at android studio tutorials on youtube and I find it very interesting. I'd like to know if android studio can be used in complement of Eclipse +ADT.

Is it possible to use android studio and it's WYSIWYG features to create the layout of the app and then go back in eclipse to edit the java code of it ?

thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it, but it's going to be so inconvenient that I'm not sure why you'd want to.

The biggest problem you'll run into is that Eclipse and Android Studio can't share the same project. They can share the same source tree on disk, but you'll need to maintain separate project + build files for each environment. See [Using gradle project in both Eclipse and IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21854335/using-gradle-project-in-both-eclipse-and-idea/21865928#21865928) for inspiration on that.

Comment: I see more and more projects on GitHub using Android Studio, so if you plan on integrating 3rd party libraries you should take a more serious look at Android Studio.